# Image Encryption using 3DES

Tags: encryption, 3des

I am doing encryption and decryption of an image using 3DES. After encrypting an image I am not able to see an encrypted image. Can any one please tell me why is this happening? I am using a jpeg image to encrypt. All this process has been done in Java.

Comment: If you encrypt the file, not the image data itself, the output clearly won't be an image anymore. Raw encryption output looks like random bytes, and those are very rarely valid images.

Comment: Yes you got it right @CodesInChaos. But I was looking forward to display that image in User interface. Will it be possible??

Comment: With a bitmap(or some other lossless format like png) instead of jpeg, you could apply encryption the the actual pixels.

Comment: I just have tried the same with bitmap image, still encrypted image is not visible.

Comment: Don't encrypt the file. Encrypt the pixels. For this you need to first load the file, and then encrypt the buffer which contains the pixels.

Answer (score 2):

After performing the Triple DES encryption the image is no longer readable as a JPG file until it has been decrypted. That’s generally the purpose of encryption to allow you to transfer that image and ensure it will be safe until it is read the intended recipient who has the private keys

Comment: Thnx for the fast reply sir, but can we get any technical proof on this? coz my guide is asking for a technical proof.